# What are the steps needed in order to isolate ASP.NET Core Identity inside a .NET Standard Class Library targeting a SQL Server database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, .net-standard

I am currently working on a legacy application and we need to re-implement the Authentication and Authorization part in a separate .NET Standard library using ASP.NET Core Identity.

The starting point and implementation path is not clear for me. I installed the following packages:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
```

I don't know how to configure it to use SQL Server or to run migrations.

I apologize if I'm asking simplistic questions.
Please help if you can.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by going though some of the tutorials.  [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

I moved a legacy user database over to asp .net identity recently what i ended up doing was creating the identity tables and then creating a sql script which migrated all of my users over to the new data structure.   The only trick was converting the passwords.